# Character Type implicit subtraction not working in C

Tags: c, character

```
#include <stdio.h>

char decryptFun(int shift, char pt_letter);
int mod(int x, int y);

int main() {
    char f = 'f';
    char r = 'r';
    char y = 'y';

    int encryptKey = 3;
    int test = 'f' - 'a';
    printf("%d", test);
    printf("%c", decryptFun(encryptKey, f));
    printf("%c", decryptFun(encryptKey, r));
    printf("%c", decryptFun(encryptKey, y));
   
    return 0;
}

int mod(int x, int y) {
    while (x < 0) {
        x += y;
    }
    return x % y;
}

char decryptFun(int shift, char pt_letter) {
    int letterPosition = (int) pt_letter - 'a';
    int rawDecryptedLetter = mod((letterPosition + 3), 26);
    char decryptedLetter = (char)rawDecryptedLetter;
    return decryptedLetter;
}
```

I am doing a school assignment wherein I am required to index the letters of the alphabet from 0 ("a") to 25 ("z"). I am trying to convert letters to this format by performing subtraction. ex. int test = 'f' - 'a'.
However, in debugging I see that the stored value of that variable "test" is an absurd number. Where it should be the difference of their ascii indexes (102 - 97 = 5), the variable shows that its value is -858993460. In debugging, I can see that both 'f' and 'a' have their correct ascii values of 102 and 97. Why is this subtraction not working?

Comment: `decryptFun` returns a raw value from 0 to 25. You need to add `'a'` back to it if you want a letter from a to z. Aside from that, it does not look like `test` would have a value like −858993460. Maybe you printed the address of `test` instead of its value. But we cannot tell because you have not shown us the debugger input and output. If your problem persists after correcting the missing edition, then edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: _Side note:_ If you use `unsigned char pt_letter` and `unsigned char letterPosition`, you can replace `mod` with [just] `(letterposition + 3) % 26` I'd change all the signed stuff to unsigned.

Comment: Also note that you have passed in encryptKey into `decryptFun`, but you don't actually use it. You have hard coded it to 3 in the function.

Comment: Try changing the `%c` format specifiers to `%d` and add `\n` to the end and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by @Craig Estey use `unsigned char`

`decryptFun` can be simplify to `return 'a' + (pt_letter - 'a' + shift) % 26; }`

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char decryptFun(unsigned int shift, unsigned char pt_letter);

int main() {
    char f = 'f';
    char r = 'r';
    char y = 'y';

    unsigned int encryptKey = 3;
    int test = 'f' - 'a';
    printf("%d\n", test);
    printf("%c\n", decryptFun(encryptKey, f));
    printf("%c\n", decryptFun(encryptKey, r));
    printf("%c\n", decryptFun(encryptKey, y));

    return 0;
}


unsigned char decryptFun(unsigned int shift, unsigned char pt_letter) {
    return 'a' + (pt_letter - 'a' + shift) % 26;
}
```